# Correctly instantiating a nested fields_for without showing older saved objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested, nested-forms

I have a nested form that instantiates as  this :

```
- 2.times { @organization.referrals.build }
- form_for @organization do |f|
  = f.error_messages
  - f.fields_for :referrals do |f|
```

Except, the nested forms are supposed to be always new and unique. Where as this form shows previously created objects as well.

So I tried to write as so..

```
- 2.times { @organization.referrals.build }
- form_for @organization do |f|
  = f.error_messages
  - f.fields_for @organization.referrals.select{|r| r.new_record? } do |f|
```

But now I do not see 2 blank forms, and I can not save my object because it tries to pass `Organization.referral` (which is not a method) instead of `Organization.referrals` .

**Question 1**

How do I create 2 blank forms?

**Question 2**

How do I get this to pass correctly ( as it does in the first example ) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

## model

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :referrals
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :referrals
end
```

## view

```
<%= form_for @organization do |f| %>
  <% 2.times do |i| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :referrals, @organization.referrals.build, :index => i do |rf| %>
       <%= rf.text_field :some_referral_attribute %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry i marked your answer correct thinking it was theoretically accurate, but in actuality, no fields get generated when I run this.

Comment: If you can post your output and actual code (not pseudo code) that would be extremely helpful in getting an accurate answer, since what I pasted is technically correct, but you may need to tweak something depending on your setup.